# Запрограммить автонастройку языка - по данным настройки языка в системе

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone

В моем приложении - пользователь при первом старте сам выбирает язык.

А наверное удобнее было бы сделать так чтобы при первом старте приложения настройка языка в приложении происходила автоматически - сканируя настройки системы. А если такого языка который стоит в системе - нет в приложении - то выставлялся бы английский например!

Как можно сие реализовать - помогите - наведите на путь правильный )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот тут подробно все описано](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial), выбор английского при отсутствии в приложении требуемой локали делается автоматом

Забыл добавить - если будете проверять на симмуляторе имейте в виду что как минимум в старых версиях там иногда не переключался  язык в приложении до перезапуска симмулятора и это именно его глюк, а не приложения

Comment: Благодарю!